# Cypress: Validate Json Object

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am kind of new to cypress.io, I am making a post call, and in return i get a json object.

According to cypress.io documentation, I should be using below code:

```
expect(response.body).to.have.property('code','unauthorized')
```

But when i run the test then i get blow error:

[image]

Can anyone help me how I can fix this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit confused about 2 arguments for the `.property('code', 'unauthorized')`? Are they key-value pair `code: unauthorized` in your json object? Could you try to find the property `code` only, like `expect(response.body).to.have.property('code');` and see the result? Also, make sure your response body doesn't have any additional property in the JSON schema, like `body.data`

Answer (score 1):

I am able to access the json object, by including console log and checking the response in the console log. The right way to access the json object in my case was:

```
expect(response.body).to.eq({"code":"unauthorized"})
```